# Locked balance in my wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, wallet-recovery, balance

I have transferred bitcoin form copay to my friend wallet 4 months ago and I just realized that my coin never sent to my friend's wallet and status in Copay wallet is "Locked Balance". My question is how can I unlock my balance and how can this happen?:(

Thanks